# How to set superscript and subscript position in same vertical line in word document using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, subscript, superscript

I am trying to add superscript and subscripts using apache poi in word file but not getting in same like below

getting like this
but i need proper like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhWyX.png

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I'd suggest watching [How to write a superscript and subscript at the same time in Word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ztgn3neikY) and then make a Word doc just containing your desired result. Then, use POI to read that file and investigate how it was encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility to have something like this [image] in a Word document is inserting an equation of form ***e*<sup>x</sup>**.

In Word GUI one would select **Insert** > **Equation** > ***e*<sup>x</sup>**.

Using Apache POI this can be done using following code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTSSubSup;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMathArg;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTText;

public class CreateWordFormulaSubSup {
    
 static CTOMath createOMathSupSub(String eText, String supText, String subText) {
  CTOMath ctOMath = CTOMath.Factory.newInstance();
  CTSSubSup ctSSubSup = ctOMath.addNewSSubSup();
  
  CTOMathArg ctOMathArg = ctSSubSup.addNewE();
  CTR ctR = ctOMathArg.addNewR();
  CTText ctText = ctR.addNewT2();
  ctText.setStringValue(eText);
  
  ctOMathArg = ctSSubSup.addNewSup();
  ctR = ctOMathArg.addNewR();
  ctText = ctR.addNewT2();
  ctText.setStringValue(supText);
  
  ctOMathArg = ctSSubSup.addNewSub();
  ctR = ctOMathArg.addNewR();
  ctText = ctR.addNewT2();
  ctText.setStringValue(subText);

  return ctOMath;
 }

 static void createOMathInParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, CTOMath ctOMath) {
  CTOMath ctOMathTemp = paragraph.getCTP().addNewOMath();
  paragraph.getCTP().setOMathArray(paragraph.getCTP().getOMathArray().length-1, ctOMath);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Formula: ");
    
  createOMathInParagraph(paragraph, createOMathSupSub("2000", "+2000", "-180"));
  
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(" text after formula.");
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordFormulaSubSup.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, How do i change font family of that 3 values ?

Comment: @Sharana Avali: You won't. At least not compatible with all word processing applications which are able to open `*.docx` files. Microsoft Word is able to interpret word processing markup language run properties for the officeDocument math markup language text run. But that is Microsoft only. Per default officeDocument math only has one font. That is Cambria Math for Microsoft Word and Liberation for Libreoffice Writer.